# morse to text and recursive search of combination words

Tags: python

Hi i write a code which has two function first function which convert simply from morse to text and second which get all the possible combination of words if there is no space between and it find recursively.

The problem is that the second function recursively get the possible combination works fine but the ***first*** function is not simple convert morse to plain text it throw the error.

this is my code :

```
import re
morseFile="""A   .-
B   -...
C   -.-.
D   -..
E   .
F   ..-.
G   --.
H   ....
I   ..
J   .---
K   -.-
L   .-..
M   --
N   -.
O   ---
P   .--.
Q   --.-
R   .-.
S   ...
T   -
U   ..-
V   ...-
W   .--
X   -..-
Y   -.--
Z   --.."""

#simple function from moorse to text

def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    split_morse_code = morseCode.strip().split(' ')
    return ''.join([morseFile[code] for code in split_morse_code]).replace('  ',  ' ')



#this is getting all the possible combination of words works fine

morse = {code:letter for line in morseFile.split("\n") for letter,code in [line.split()]}
def decode(coded,maxLen=10):
    if not maxLen: return
    for size in range(1,min(4,len(coded))+1):
        code = coded[:size]
        if code not in morse: continue
        remaining = coded[size:]
        if not remaining: yield morse[code]
        for rest in decode(remaining,maxLen-1):
            yield morse[code] + rest

print(sum(1 for _ in decode("-.-.-.--")))
for string in decode("-.-.-.--"):
    if len(string)<9: print(string)

print(decodeMorse('.'))
```

and the error it throw when run the program is this:

```
100
TETETETT
TETETEM
TETETAT
TETETW
TETENTT
TETENM
TETEKT
TETEY
TETAETT
TETAEM
TETAAT
TETAW
TETRTT
TETRM
TENTETT
TENTEM
TENTAT
TENTW
TENNTT
TENNM
TENKT
TENY
TEKETT
TEKEM
TEKAT
TEKW
TECTT
TECM
TAETETT
TAETEM
TAETAT
TAETW
TAENTT
TAENM
TAEKT
TAEY
TAAETT
TAAEM
TAAAT
TAAW
TARTT
TARM
TRTETT
TRTEM
TRTAT
TRTW
TRNTT
TRNM
TRKT
TRY
NTETETT
NTETEM
NTETAT
NTETW
NTENTT
NTENM
NTEKT
NTEY
NTAETT
NTAEM
NTAAT
NTAW
NTRTT
NTRM
NNTETT
NNTEM
NNTAT
NNTW
NNNTT
NNNM
NNKT
NNY
NKETT
NKEM
NKAT
NKW
NCTT
NCM
KETETT
KETEM
KETAT
KETW
KENTT
KENM
KEKT
KEY
KAETT
KAEM
KAAT
KAW
KRTT
KRM
CTETT
CTEM
CTAT
CTW
CNTT
CNM
CKT
CY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/taimoor/dala.py", line 54, in <module>
    print(decodeMorse('.'))
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/taimoor/dala.py", line 33, in decodeMorse
    return ''.join([morseFile[code] for code in split_morse_code]).replace('  ',  ' ')
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/taimoor/dala.py", line 33, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([morseFile[code] for code in split_morse_code]).replace('  ',  ' ')
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The output of first function morse to plain text should be 'e' but it throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
return '.join([morseFile[code] for code in split_morse_code]).replace('  ',  ' ')
```

to this

```
return '.join([morse[code] for code in split_morse_code]).replace('  ',  ' ')
```

That is to say:

morseFile -> morse